# Error when applying tokenize to json with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tokenize

I have been following a tutorial that I can see has been popular among users however, there is an error that persists I have found no resolution for.
I am using PyCharm and Python3.6 with this code. I appreciate the time help and help, thank you.

#### Code:

```
import json
from collections import Counter
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string


with open(fname, 'r', newline='\r\n') as f:
    count_all = Counter()
    for line in f:

        tweet = json.loads(line)
        terms_stop = [term for term in preprocess(tweet['text']) if term not in stop]
        terms_single = set(terms_stop)

        terms_hash = [term for term in preprocess(tweet['text']) if term.startswith('#')]
```

#### The error I am getting is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sukhivinder/PycharmProjects/mscProjectOne/sentimentJSONfile.py", line 50, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

#### Data:

```
{"created_at":"Wed Nov 15 21:37:57 +0000 2017","id":930912780831678464,"id_str":"930912780831678464","text":"Greatest Brexit speech ever? LABOUR MP\u2019s address will make your neck hairs stand up https:\/\/t.co\/5G3uEELEll","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":886309819245879296,"id_str":"886309819245879296","name":"HMS","screen_name":"HMS150446","location":"England, United Kingdom","url":null,"description":"Any R\/T is not an endorsement but a way of sharing articles received on my twitter feed which I think are interesting and want to share.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":491,"friends_count":1480,"listed_count":4,"favourites_count":12236,"statuses_count":27375,"created_at":"Sat Jul 15 19:41:42 +0000 2017","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/886676198155329538\/E8RsRDyz_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/886676198155329538\/E8RsRDyz_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/886309819245879296\/1500235099","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/5G3uEELEll","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.express.co.uk\/news\/politics\/880048\/Brexit-speech-Labour-MP-Peter-Shore-EU","display_url":"express.co.uk\/news\/politics\/\u2026","indices":[84,107]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1510781877130"}
{"created_at":"Wed Nov 15 21:37:57 +0000 2017","id":930912782056345600,"id_str":"930912782056345600","text":"RT @ThatTimWalker: This is a courageous journalist and a courageous newspaper. Would Mrs May have owned up to our Russian problem if i\u2026 ","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/#!\/download\/ipad\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPad\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2687419047,"id_str":"2687419047","name":"Elizabeth#FBPE#StopBrexit","screen_name":"epcarruthers","location":"Edinburgh and Dormont","url":null,"description":"wife,mother, grandmother, gardener, LibDemocrat, and owner of 2 delightful cats.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":248,"friends_count":185,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":18269,"statuses_count":29872,"created_at":"Tue Jul 08 15:24:35 +0000 2014","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/715085957146525696\/edS1d2lF_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/715085957146525696\/edS1d2lF_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2687419047\/1510238275","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Tue Nov 14 23:24:41 +0000 2017","id":930577252827516928,"id_str":"930577252827516928","text":"This is a courageous journalist and a courageous newspaper. Would Mrs May have owned up to our Russian problem if i\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/U83rrcqahM","display_text_range":[0,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":60606206,"id_str":"60606206","name":"Tim Walker","screen_name":"ThatTimWalker","location":"London","url":null,"description":"A point of view","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":18870,"friends_count":887,"listed_count":214,"favourites_count":8392,"statuses_count":26689,"created_at":"Mon Jul 27 14:07:16 +0000 2009","utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"Casablanca","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/914607099220496384\/dtzHhd2V_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/914607099220496384\/dtzHhd2V_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/60606206\/1398249447","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"quoted_status_id":930576544820547584,"quoted_status_id_str":"930576544820547584","quoted_status":{"created_at":"Tue Nov 14 23:21:52 +0000 2017","id":930576544820547584,"id_str":"930576544820547584","text":"Playing catch-up on Brexit-Trump-Russia? My piece from May. Read it before Cambridge Analytica (of FBI &amp; Wikileaks\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/pnUZeed6kq","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":722242009,"id_str":"722242009","name":"Carole Cadwalladr","screen_name":"carolecadwalla","location":null,"url":"https:\/\/www.theguardian.com\/profile\/carolecadwalladr","description":"Late adopter. Early giver-upper. Guardian & Observer writer.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":44945,"friends_count":1866,"listed_count":547,"favourites_count":660,"statuses_count":2899,"created_at":"Sat Jul 28 14:06:01 +0000 2012","utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"Amsterdam","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/875727729525747717\/ZAIcCXFJ_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/875727729525747717\/ZAIcCXFJ_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/722242009\/1503701353","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Playing catch-up on Brexit-Trump-Russia? My piece from May. Read it before Cambridge Analytica (of FBI &amp; Wikileaks fame!) sues @guardian into oblivion. They're trying to shut this - me, us - down. \nhttps:\/\/t.co\/KKZUJ81NE9","display_text_range":[0,225],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/KKZUJ81NE9","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.theguardian.com\/technology\/2017\/may\/07\/the-great-british-brexit-robbery-hijacked-democracy?CMP=share_btn_tw","display_url":"theguardian.com\/technology\/201\u2026","indices":[202,225]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"guardian","name":"The Guardian","id":87818409,"id_str":"87818409","indices":[131,140]}],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":169,"reply_count":113,"retweet_count":2694,"favorite_count":2551,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/pnUZeed6kq","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/930576544820547584","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[120,143]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":true,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"This is a courageous journalist and a courageous newspaper. Would Mrs May have owned up to our Russian problem if it hadn't got into newspapers? I wonder. https:\/\/t.co\/Qj8AkSxnIx","display_text_range":[0,154],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Qj8AkSxnIx","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/carolecadwalla\/status\/930576544820547584","display_url":"twitter.com\/carolecadwalla\u2026","indices":[155,178]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":2,"reply_count":5,"retweet_count":206,"favorite_count":293,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/U83rrcqahM","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/930577252827516928","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"quoted_status_id":930576544820547584,"quoted_status_id_str":"930576544820547584","quoted_status":{"created_at":"Tue Nov 14 23:21:52 +0000 2017","id":930576544820547584,"id_str":"930576544820547584","text":"Playing catch-up on Brexit-Trump-Russia? My piece from May. Read it before Cambridge Analytica (of FBI &amp; Wikileaks\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/pnUZeed6kq","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":722242009,"id_str":"722242009","name":"Carole Cadwalladr","screen_name":"carolecadwalla","location":null,"url":"https:\/\/www.theguardian.com\/profile\/carolecadwalladr","description":"Late adopter. Early giver-upper. Guardian & Observer writer.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":44945,"friends_count":1866,"listed_count":547,"favourites_count":660,"statuses_count":2899,"created_at":"Sat Jul 28 14:06:01 +0000 2012","utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"Amsterdam","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/875727729525747717\/ZAIcCXFJ_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/875727729525747717\/ZAIcCXFJ_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/722242009\/1503701353","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Playing catch-up on Brexit-Trump-Russia? My piece from May. Read it before Cambridge Analytica (of FBI &amp; Wikileaks fame!) sues @guardian into oblivion. They're trying to shut this - me, us - down. \nhttps:\/\/t.co\/KKZUJ81NE9","display_text_range":[0,225],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/KKZUJ81NE9","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.theguardian.com\/technology\/2017\/may\/07\/the-great-british-brexit-robbery-hijacked-democracy?CMP=share_btn_tw","display_url":"theguardian.com\/technology\/201\u2026","indices":[202,225]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"guardian","name":"The Guardian","id":87818409,"id_str":"87818409","indices":[131,140]}],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":169,"reply_count":113,"retweet_count":2694,"favorite_count":2551,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/pnUZeed6kq","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/930576544820547584","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[120,143]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":true,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"ThatTimWalker","name":"Tim Walker","id":60606206,"id_str":"60606206","indices":[3,17]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1510781877422"}
```

I have added the full error message in response to a user however I had a post that consisted of majority code so required further text to allow the edit to be made.

Comment: Where is the data?

Comment: Apologies. i have amended the post to include data now.

Comment: You miss the part of the traceback where it says what the actual exception is...

Comment: Thank you, I have added the full message I get when I try to run the code.

Comment: There is something wrong in your JSON data.  You need to amend the question to include JSON which exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

For the `open()` function, use a `U` in the mode string.

#### What about my problem?

I changed your `open()` call to use *[Universal Newline Support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)*.  It went...

#### From:

```
with open(fname, 'r', newline='\r\n') as f:
```

#### To:

```
with open(fname, 'rU') as f:
```

This fixed the problem in my testing.

#### What is Universal Newline Support?

From [PEP-278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/):

> This PEP discusses a way in which Python can support I/O on files which have a newline format that is not the native format on the platform, so that Python on each platform can read and import files with CR (Macintosh), LF (Unix) or CR LF (Windows) line endings.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I tried the amendments you made however the same problem is still persisting for myself. Am I right in believing this change should work for any version of python? I am currently on 3.6.